# mySQL/ MariaDB Calculate with Variables

Tags: mysql, variables, count, mariadb

I would like to have the most popular book `calculated_points` calculated by the DB. My db query works, however the `counter` is not correct. Apparently because the sorting is too late. How can I improve it for mariaDB 10.3?

Book with 10 points should get place 1.

Book with 8 points should get place 2.

Book with 4 points should get place 3.

```
SET @var = 0;
SELECT 
   (@var:=@var+1) AS counter, 
   (row1 * row2 / 4) as calculated_points 
from bookz 
WHERE kat = '6' 
  AND pubdate > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH) 
  AND pub = '1' 
  AND ratings > '1' 
  AND productType = 'pbook' 
GROUP BY title 
ORDER BY calculated_points desc 
LIMIT 256
```

Comment: Which version of MySQL? Because 8+ has [ROW_NUMBER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) and [RANK](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_rank), which can be helpful for this.   (Also some sample data, and desired output would be nice)

Comment: Yes, the following command, new for me, works perfectly for me on Maria 10.3:

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY calculated_points desc) as placement, ....

Thanxx